# Compile C executable during python package installation

Tags: python

I've got a python package which requires to compile and install executable written in C (it is helper program and acts as a script), which will need to go into proper place, i.e. same place where scripts would go ($VIRTUAL_ENV/bin, /usr/local/bin, etc).

What would be the correct way to implement this?

I found [an example](https://github.com/mkleehammer/kelvin/blob/master/build_exe.py), but it works only when using pip to install the package, but fail when I try to use `python setup.py install`: they will build the executable, but will not install it during the "install bdist_egg" stage.